# Continuously consume kafka message with Kafka Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I want to build a processor to transform one Kafka json messages into several dataframes. I want to process `100,000` messages in batch or in `10 second` intervals.

This is what I have:

```py
    datastruct = []
    lead = 1
    for msg in consumer:
        start_time = time.time()
        record = json.loads(msg.value)
        datastruct.append(record)
        current_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = current_time-start_time
        lead = lead + 1
        if(len(datastruct) >= 100000 or elapsed_time > 5):
            consumer.pause()
            *** transformation here ***
            datastruct.clear()
            consumer.resume()
    if consumer is not None:
        consumer.close()
```

Let say I have about `699,000` message at first.

My goal is to continue to check if there are any new message for each interval, but it stops if there are no messages in my kafka and not wait until new messages come. And it was only processed `600,000` messages, and left the `99,000` messages behind.

Any help is appreciated.